# How can i split string per line on file

Tags: arrays, perl, file, split

I have a file that contain string like this:

```
- ' *[0-9]-? [^a-c]@[*-^a-c]' '' < temp-test/758.inp.325.1
- ' *[0-9]-? [^a-c]@[*-^a-c]' '' < temp-test/759.inp.325.3
- ' *[0-9]@[[9-B]??[0-9]-[^-[^0-9]-[a-c][^a-c]' 'NEW' < temp-test/1133.inp.487.1`enter code here`
- ' *[0-9]@[[9-B]??[0-9]-[^-[^0-9]-[a-c][^a-c]' 'NEW' < temp-test/1134.inp.487.2
- '"@@' 'm' < input/ruin.1890
```

I want to split this string per line to be 2 part , and i hope the result like this:

```
- line 1: array[0]=' *[0-9]-? [^a-c]@[*-^a-c]'; array [1]='' < temp-test/758.inp.325.1
- line 2: array[0]=' *[0-9]-? [^a-c]@[*-^a-c]'; array [1]='' < temp-test/759.inp.325.3
- line 3: array[0]=' *[0-9]@[[9-B]??[0-9]-[^-[^0-9]-[a-c][^a-c]'; array[1]='NEW' < temp-test/1133.inp.487.1
- line 4: array[0]=' *[0-9]@[[9-B]??[0-9]-[^-[^0-9]-[a-c][^a-c]'; array[1]='NEW' < temp-test/1134.inp.487.2
- line 5: array[0]='"@@'; array[1]='m' < input/ruin.1890
```

and the code i've try is like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# location of universe file
$tc = "/root/Desktop/SIEMENS/replace/testplans.alt/universe";

# open file universe;
open( F, "<$tc" );
@test_case = <F>;

while ( $i < 5 ) {

    $test_case[$i] =~ s/ //;
    @isi = split( / /, $test_case[$i] );

    if ( $#isi == 2 ) {
        print "Input1:" . $isi[0] . "\n";
        print "Input2:" . $isi[1] . "\n";
        print "Input3:" . $isi[2] . "\n";
    }

    $i++;
}
```

I am confused because i can't slit that string with " " (space), because each of line have different order space and i can't get to be 2 part.
Thank you.

Comment: Don't use split for this, use a regular expression.  http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Please edit your post with clear example and clear output what you exactly want.

Comment: It's far from clear what is in your input file and your required output. Please copy the data exactly and highlight it with Ctrl-K as you have done with your Perl code

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# this stuff just gives me your data for testing

my $data =<<EOF;
' [0-9]-? [^a-c]\@[-^a-c]' '' < temp-test/758.inp.325.1
' [0-9]-? [^a-c]\@[-^a-c]' '' < temp-test/759.inp.325.3
' *[0-9]\@[[9-B]??[0-9]-[^-[^0-9]-[a-c][^a-c]' 'NEW' < temp-test/1133.inp.487.1
' *[0-9]\@[[9-B]??[0-9]-[^-[^0-9]-[a-c][^a-c]' 'NEW' < temp-test/1134.inp.487.2
'"\@\@' 'm' < input/ruin.1890
EOF

for my $line (split(/\n/,$data))
{

    # this re splits your strings according
    # to what I perceive to be your requirements

    if ($line =~ /^(.*)('.*?' <.*)$/)
    {
        print("array[0]=$1; array[1]=$2;\n")
    }
}


1;
```

Output:

```
array[0]=' [0-9]-? [^a-c]@[-^a-c]' ; array[1]='' < temp-test/758.inp.325.1;
array[0]=' [0-9]-? [^a-c]@[-^a-c]' ; array[1]='' < temp-test/759.inp.325.3;
array[0]=' *[0-9]@[[9-B]??[0-9]-[^-[^0-9]-[a-c][^a-c]' ; array[1]='NEW' < temp-test/1133.inp.487.1
array[0]=' *[0-9]@[[9-B]??[0-9]-[^-[^0-9]-[a-c][^a-c]' ; array[1]='NEW' < temp-test/1134.inp.487.2;
array[0]='"@@' ; array[1]='m' < input/ruin.1890;
```

Applied to your code it might look something like this:

```
while ($i<5)
{

    $test_case[$i] =~ /^(.*)('.*?' <.*)$/;
    @isi = ($1,$2);

    print "Input1:".$isi[0]."\n";
    print "Input2:".$isi[1]."\n";

    $i++;
}
```